# Why my first tab is missing for local menu tasks defined by hook_menu()?

Tags: routes

I am learning how to use hook_menu(). I am at a point where I have a question and not figure it out. I have a local task button inline with View and Edit and I want 4 sub-local_task buttons. See chart below.

```
View | Edit | **Outcomes** |

*Outcomes Viewer* | Add New User | Add Bulk Ghost | Registration Report
```

However, the first button(*Outcomes Viewer*) is missing and I cannot figure out how to get it to show up. Below is the menu code within the function. The *Outcomes Viewer* is a view. I am mixing this with some custom code and views as well. 
(*Drupal 7, Views 3)

```
$items['node/%node/ecg-outcomes'] = array(
    'title' => 'Outcomes',
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 50,
  );
  $items['node/%node/ecg-outcomes/'] = array(
    'title' => 'Outcomes Viewer',
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => -10,
  );
  $items['node/%node/ecg-outcomes/add-bulk-ghost'] = array(
    'title' => 'Add Bulk Ghost',
    'page callback' => 'entity_ghost_participant_report',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'entity_ghost_participant_access_report_tab',
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'file' => 'entity_ghost_participant.reports.inc',
    'weight' => 11,
  );
  $items['node/%node/ecg-outcomes/add-new-user'] = array(
    'title' => 'Add New User',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 14,
  );
```

Comment: If you can reduce the scope of the code and (thus the question), I'd try it locally to work it out. As it is though, the posted code has a lot of dependencies, so I can't easily do that. The only thing that sort of stands out to me is that you don't have a MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK, which you might want. Can't recall having used it recently though, so it might not be relevant.

Comment: I copied your code into a module and it works. - http://imgur.com/ZVDXzIE - the only other things I did was added dummy access & page callback functions to match your items and removed the 'file' param for my ease.

Comment: I would say the problem relates to the fact that your outcomes views page is a view, because mine was not. Maybe something conflicting with your views path/menu settings and this menu hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 3 menu items and 2 view pages. The parent menu and the default menu will share some configuration.

```
  $items['node/%node/ecg-outcomes/add-new-user'] = array(
    'title' => 'Add New User',
    'page callback' => 'SOME CALLBACK',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => -9,
  );
  $items['node/%node/ecg-outcomes/add-bulk-ghost'] = array(
    'title' => 'Add bulk',
    'page callback' => 'SOME CALLBACK',
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK ,
    'weight' => -8,
  );
  $items['node/%node/ecg-outcomes/registration-report'] = array(
    'title' => 'Registration Report',
    'page callback' => 'SOME CALLBACK',
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK ,
    'weight' => -7,
  );

  return $items;
```

As the outcome-viewer is set up as a view and you want it as the default menu tab, you need to set up two almost identical pages in your view as follows:

**View Page 1:**

```
Path: node/%/ecg-outcomes
Menu: Type : Menu tab, Title : Outcomes, weight : 50
```

**View Page 2:**

```
Path: node/%/ecg-outcomes/outcomes-viewer
Menu: Type : Default menu tab, Title : Outcomes Viewer, weight : -10
```

**METHOD 2**
I think it can also be done with 4 menu items and 1 view page, in which case you only define view page 1, and include this menu item:

```
$items['node/%node/ecg-outcomes/outcomes-viewer'] = array(
    'title' => 'Add New User', // NO page callback and access callback necessary
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => -9,
);
```